# TNS Listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor -> OracleInternal.Network Error

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am very new to connecting to Oracle DB, I am having challenges as to using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
Now I get this Exception

TNS Listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor -> OracleInternal.Network

And this is when connecting to the Database

I have the following information about the Database :

Database name : employeeDB
SID : ORCL

Now Adding the connection string it gave me in App.Config Looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
            <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
                type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.122.19.1"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
        <version number="*">
            <dataSources>
                <dataSource alias="SAM"
                    descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
            </dataSources>
        </version>
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

And the Code used to connect to the Database looks like this  :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = "User ID=SYSTEM; Password=ADMIN1234; Data Source=SAM;";
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("I am connected!");
        label1.Text = "Connected to Oracle Database!";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

But i get this Exception `TNS Listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor -> OracleInternal.Network`

What am I not doing correctly? This is my first time connecting to Oracle Db from a C# application

Comment: Please post output (on the host where Oracle database instance runs with Oracle admin user ) of `tnsping ORCL` and `lsnrctl status`.

Comment: If sid is `ORCL` you should use `Data Source=ORCL` but verify first as suggested by @pifor

Comment: I have resolved it

Answer (score 0):

I have Resolved the issue. Running

`show parameters service_name` on `sqlplus` showed the service name then i used it on the code and it connected without worries. Thanks everyone